# ASP.net GridView doesn't show

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datasource

I have GridView on my page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And i use button to set grid view datasource:

```
DataAdapter adapter=new DataAdapter(SqlCommand,SqlConn);
DataTable tbl=new Datatable();
adapter.Fill(tbl);
GridView1.DataSource=tbl;
```

From debug mode i can see that datatable is filled property and does contain data. But i can see nothing in the screen. What's the problem

P.S. Found the simillar question except that in that question no data source was set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to call databind method here.Use following code :

```
 DataAdapter adapter=new DataAdapter(SqlCommand,SqlConn);
 DataTable tbl=new Datatable();
 adapter.Fill(tbl);
 GridView1.DataSource=tbl;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Let me know it is working for you or not ?

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. There was another problem, but i solved it myself. Could you tell me why my question was rated as negative?

Comment: I don't know who rated it -ve.But this is real problem

Comment: Would you like to know me what is the actual problem ?

Comment: First was that i didn't used `GridView1.DataBind();` and the second was quite simple - visual studio didn't rebuilt the project. So I Restarted studio and all worked.